Why does adding mass in different places affect the moment of inertia differently in these two cases?

In one scenario, a bicycle designer adds cylindrical weights to the spokes of a bicycle wheel, thinking that it will bring the mass closer to the axle and decrease the moment of inertia. However, this actually increases the moment of inertia, making the wheel harder to rotate.

In another scenario, a child curls up inside the center of a tire. This decreases the tire’s moment of inertia, making the tire roll faster.


Both situations involve adding mass to a system, so why does the moment of inertia increase in one case but decrease in the other, even though both involve bringing mass closer to the center? What’s the key difference between the two situations?


Both situations involve adding mass to a system ...

Not so. Scenario (1) involves adding mass - but scenario (2) is only re-arranging mass that is already there. The total mass of the child and the tire in scenario (2) is constant - no mass is added to the system.
Since the moment of inertia about a given axis is the sum of the mass of each element of a system times the square of its distance from the axis, then adding mass to a system always increases its moment of inertia unless the extra is added on the axis itself, when it leaves the moment of inertia unchanged. Certainly adding mass to a system cannot reduce its moment of inertia about a given axis.
However, re-arranging the existing mass within a system can reduce its moment of inertia if the mass is re-arranged so as to bring it closer to the axis.

Thanks for the explanation, but just to clarify, in that scenario from my textbook, the child starts outside the tire and then curls up inside the center of it. So in this case, mass is being added to the system (the tire), not just rearranged within it. At least that's how I interpreted it. Here is the full question:
"Two children are rolling automobile tires down a hill. One child claims that the tire will roll faster if one of them curls up in the tire's center. The other child claims that will cause the tire to roll more slowly. Which child is correct?"

@HaniIsmael Then the question is ambiguous, since it is not clear whether both tires have children inside them but in different positions, or if only one tire has a child inside it.

Thank you for the response. To clarify the situation and make it less ambiguous, let's assume that the question is asking about the difference between rolling a tire down a hill with and without a child curling up inside it. In other words, one tire rolls down the hill empty, and the other has a child curling up in the center.
With this assumption, it seems like we're dealing with an "adding mass" scenario, since the child is being placed inside the tire. Given that the child curls up right at the center, I believe the mass is being added very close to the axis of rotation.

My question is: does this assumption make it so that the moment of inertia decreases because the added mass is near the axis of rotation, or does the mere addition of mass automatically increase the moment of inertia, regardless of its position?

@HaniIsmael As my answer says, if mass is added to a system it always increases the moment of inertia unless its is added exactly at the axis, in which case the moment of inertia is unchanged.

I agree with your explanation, but my textbook’s answer key suggests that when a child curls up in the center of the tire, the coefficient of the moment of inertia decreases, speeding up the roll. It is referring to the equation $v = \sqrt{\frac{2gh}{C+1}}$, where C is the moment of inertia coefficient. As the child moves closer to the center, C decreases, reducing the moment of inertia and increasing the velocity.

That said, the answer key could be wrong, or this might be an oversimplification. Could this be a misunderstanding of how added mass near the axis affects the moment of inertia? I’d appreciate your thoughts.

@HaniIsmael I think your dimensionless moment of inertia coefficient $C$ must be $\frac I {mR^2}$ (where $R$ is the radius of the tire), in which case adding mass inside the tire can reduce $C$, even though it increases $I$.
